# Nav bar and menu drop down from inside

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, elementor

I want to have my drop-down menu élément showing from inside and the pointer being on the bottom of the nav-bar like in the picture how should i do it on wordpress website with elementor or custom css. I tried to change the padding but nothing is happenning.
[What i want it to be like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfYu8.jpg)[What i have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew1pk.png)

I have tried to inspect the page and add the padding of the pointer but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The inner ul li would be effected by padding if preceded by display:block.

```
Try using this
ul{padding-left:0px;}
ul li{padding-left:10px;font-size:15px;}
ul li ul{display:block; padding-left: 30px;(change 30 by req left space)
ul li ul li{ font-size:11px;}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Here is the website:  https://port-de-conakry.quantahive.net/ it's a Wordpress website.

Comment: Did you fixed the navigation, i can see it is working .

Comment: The navigation didn't have a problem. I just want to had it a new style like in the first image of my question.Sorry if i am not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. now i see there are two image links. In order to achieve "what you want it like to be" you need to override "position:absolute" of .wpr-nav-menu .wpr-sub-menu  from wordpress style. 
The present class effect is coming from plugins/royal-elementor-addons/assets/css/frontend.min.css and as per wordpress standard, it can be over ride from wordpress backend using Apperance   >> Customize >> Additional CSS.  
Create a class with same name in wordpress additional css interface .wpr-sub-menu{position: none !important;} and save it to check effect in frontend.